# Flag an already flagged queststion?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I've flagged [How to make order with price more than 100.000.000 magento 1.8](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174458/how-to-make-order-with-price-more-than-100-000-000-magento-1-8) as (indeed) duplicate and a comment was added to querist post.

> Now I can't flag this to be deleted.

Shouldn't it be possible to add another flag for these kind of questions?

Maybe you allow a 2nd flag with asking for reason in next step? Delete b/c of `exact duplicate` or `other reason`? The querist could be informed about this to continue reading at the original question ...

ATM you can only call for moderator intervention (or abuse, spam - what it isn't is) ...